# Could not load the config file in service - vendor js 65401

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, angular-services, angular9

[image]

It works fine in injecting into components. problem occurs in service injection.

I am using runtime configuration for end points.it works in components.i can able to change in runtime but throws an error when injecting in  other services global

```
export class AppConfigService {
    static settings: IAppConfig;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
load() {

    const jsonFile = `../assets/config/config.json`;
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response : IAppConfig) => {
           AppConfigService.settings = <IAppConfig>response;
           console.log('Config Loaded');
           console.log( AppConfigService.settings);
           resolve();
           
        }).catch((response: any) => {
           reject(`Could not load the config file`);
        });
    });
}
```

}

in the app module provide app intializers:

```
providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true},


export function initializeApp(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return appConfigService.load();
  }
}
```

when integrate with app service have the error. could not load the config file. But it works in a component.

auth.service
import { AppConfigService } from 'app/app-config.service';

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

   apiServer = AppConfigService.settings.apiServer;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { 

      console.log(this.apiServer.link1);
    }
```

Reference link :[reference url](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/11/27/handling-angular-environments-in-continuous-delivery-with-red-hat-openshift/)

[App.settings - the Angular way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-way)
[Loading configuration files in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749115/loading-configuration-files-in-angular-6)
[Load Config JSON File In Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110817/load-config-json-file-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have added you an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkuwef?file=src/app/app.module.ts

https://github.com/misanche/angular-pkuwef/